# CakePHP 3.0 .json missing template error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am migrating an existing 2.5 app over to 3.0. I am getting an error of missing template when using json requests now which I did not have in the older version.

I don't see any step that I might have missed.

routes.php

```
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);
```

PagesController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}

public function request(){

    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    $userName = $this->request->data['name'];
    $userCompany = $this->request->data['company'];
    $userEmail = $this->request->data['email'];
    $userPhone = $this->request->data['phone'];

    //send an email

}
```

The previous app was able to detect the request type and return with the same type. There was no need to set the render.

Comment: Have you set `$this->autoRender = false` in your action?

Comment: Try adding a `return` at  the end of your action.

Comment: as with my 2.5 version cakePHP see's the .json extension and handles accordantly. If it handles it right then I should not need `$this->autoRender = false`

Comment: sorry `return` did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that because I am trying to access an action on the PagesController.php that the routes.php was trying to pass it through the display action which looked for the template.

routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```

PagesController.php

```
public function display()
{
    $path = func_get_args();

    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage'));

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingTemplateException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```